# Newenvironment scope not well defined

Tags: environments

I am trying to write an newenvironment theorem and another one as exercice. According to my results the scope of the environments are not well define:

1. How to get rid of the blacksquare inserted at the end of the line?
2. How to well fix the scope of the environment exercice and exemple?
   Thank you.

Below is a picture showing what I am trying to get.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, arrows}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}

\newcommand{\phase}[1]{\par\medskip\textbf{#1}\par\nopagebreak}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,chains,automata,shapes,matrix,positioning,scopes,calc}

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

% Exercice box    
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{exempleT}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exemple}% environment name
{
\par
    \begin{exempleT}
        %\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        %\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        \tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
        %\ignorespacesafterend
    \end{exempleT}
}

\newtheorem{exerciceT}{Exercice}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exercice}% environment name
{
\par
    \begin{eBox}\begin{exerciceT}
        %\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        %\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
        %\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        \hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
        %\ignorespacesafterend
    \end{exerciceT}\end{eBox}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{exemple}
        Soit l'expression suivante:

        \code{nouvelle\_valeur = ancienne\_valeur + 12}

        Après avoir lu les symboles issus de l'instruction de l'exemple ci-dessus, l'analyseur va les regrouper en jetons.
    \end{exemple}

Ainsi, considérant cette expression: \code{nouvelle\_valeur = ancienne\_valeur + fact * 1}, pendant la phase de génération de code intermédiaire, ce code de haut niveau est traduit dans un langage de bas niveau, c'est-à-dire en langage machine ainsi:

    \begin{exercice}
            Construisez l'automate à pile pouvant reconnaître le langage $L = \{w|w = a^nb^m| n \geq m\}$
    \end{exercice}      
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Pour l'expression régulière $\epsilon$, l'AFD correspondant est:
            \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=1cm, initial text = Début]
                \node[initial, state](1){1};
                \node[state, accepting](2)[right=of 1]{2};

                \path[->] (1) edge node {$\epsilon$}   (2);
            \end{tikzpicture}

        \item Pour l'expression régulière \code{a}, l'AFD correspondant est:
            Ceci n'est pas encore défini.

    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{exercice}
        Soit l'instruction suivante:
        \begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b, caption=, label=listing:exempleLexeme_2, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
            int max(int i);
        \end{lstlisting}

        Quel est le nombre total de jetons présents dans cette instruction?

        \emph{Réponse:}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item l’analyseur lexical lit d’abord \code{int} et le trouve valide et l'accepte comme jeton;
            \item \code{max} est lu par celui-ci et s’avère être un nom de fonction valide;
            \item ensuite le symbole \code{(} est reconnu comme jeton;
            \item \code{int}  est aussi un jeton, de même que \code{i} et enfin \code{)};
        \end{itemize}

        Le nombre total de jetons est: 7. Les jetons sont: \code{int}, \code{max}, \code{(}, \code{int}, \code{i}, \code{)}, \code{;}
    \end{exercice}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean black box? You inserted a `\blacksquare` command yourself...?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant `\blacksquare`. I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: `\newenvironment` takes 3 arguments `{name}{begin code} {end code}` you have consistently omitted the last argument, just avoiding an error by leaving a blank line so the 3rd argument is `{\par}` but I woulld guess you intended  `\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
        %\ignorespacesafterend
    \end{exerciceT}\end{eBox}` to be the end code of  `exercice` ???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this was I meant: `\newenvironment{exercice}% environment name
{%{begin code}
 \par %Small vertical space between current Exercice and previous one
 \begin{eBox}\begin{exerciceT}
 %Exercice body
 \hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}         
 \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces         %\ignorespacesafterend
 %End of exercice body
 \end{exerciceT}\end{eBox}
}%{end code}`

Comment: @cProg that is missing the end-code argument. The body  of the environment does not get inserted here `%Exercice body` it is inserted after `\end{eBox}`